# How to extract Microsoft OneNote attached files?

Tags: c#, onenote

I have a collection of Microsoft OneNote 2010 notebooks.

The various pages within the these notebooks have a lot of attached files that I need to programatically extract, as there are too many files and I have too few man hours to do this by hand.

The documentation I've seen on OneNote Interop hasn't been particularly helpful. Ideally I'd like to preserve the original file's metadata (filename, date created, date modified) but at this point I'll take any solution that yields the files I need extracted.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?